# How to make a timer for an online exam>

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

Friends I am making online examination for a collage project. It's almost completed but now my problem is I want a timer for that online examination exam project.

This is the js code:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var d = new Date();

        var month = d.getMonth()+1;
        var day = d.getDate();

        var output = ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + day + ' / ' + ((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month + ' / ' + d.getFullYear();

        document.getElementById("datespan").innerHTML = output;
    });

    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        if(localStorage.getItem("counter")){
          if(localStorage.getItem("counter") >= 10){
            var value = 0;
          }else{
            var value = localStorage.getItem("counter");
          }
        }else{
          var value = 0;
        }
        document.getElementById('divCounter').innerHTML = value;

        var counter = function (){
          if(value >= 10){
            localStorage.setItem("counter", 30);
            value = 0;
          }else{
            value = parseInt(value)-1;
            localStorage.setItem("counter", value);
          }
          document.getElementById('divCounter').innerHTML = value;
        };

        var interval = setInterval(function (){counter();}, 1000);
            });
```

HTML:

```
 <div><h3>Remaining Time : <div id="divCounter"></div></span></h3></div>
```

But the problem is, it's just loading in negative side, just like this

[image]

how to start a specific time (minutes eg: 30 minutes to 0 minutes ) and stop timer in 0 and also I want to know how to stop this timer when the user submit the exam or when time is over.

Comment: clear your interval when your counter reaches down to 0 or when the exam is submitted `clearInterval(interval)`

Comment: Depending on how official this is you should consider validating the time on the server as well. If you keep everything on the client side someone could hijack your timer variable and change it so he could have an unlimited amount of time to answer your questions.

Comment: I can't upvote Jonas' comment enough. Never rely on Javascript for anything critical. It's trivial for anyone to alter it using the Developer tools. You don't need a lot of skill. JS is great for enhancing user experience and creating convenience, but any business logic it implements, such as this, must be verified on the server-side if you value the integrity of your application and its data.